# Add a file as entropy source for /dev/random

Tags: linux, random, entropy

**What I have:** A large file containing lots of secret, true-random bytes (yes, I'm sure they're not merely pseudo-random). I'll call it F.

**What I want to do**: Tell Linux that it can use this file as an entropy source for `/dev/random` (each byte should be estimated at a full 8 bits of entropy)

**What I already know about and don't want to be lectured about**:

- `/dev/urandom`
- Existing tools for collecting entropy from other devices in the system

**What I'm looking for**: A shell command or the name of a tool (and the relevant function) that will either:

- Append F to `/dev/random`
- Cause accesses to `/dev/random` to consume bytes from F as if it were a device, without reusing any

Is this possible? What are the security implications?

Comment: Can I just ask... why? What is the problem that you are solving by doing this? I mean, "for funsies" is completely fine, I just want to be sure you're not doing it because you expect some kind of tangible security improvement.

Comment: This has nothing to do with system security. We have an application that consumes tons of raw entropy (it MUST be raw, not the output of /dev/urandom) and we have decided the most "world compatible" way to consume this entropy is through /dev/random.

Comment: You can't really "consume" entropy. Besides, /dev/urandom is designed to provide an essentially unlimited CSRPNG through the use of AES-CTR keyed from /dev/random, which means you're guaranteed to have strong random numbers as long as you've got even a bare minimum of collected entropy. You'd have to run some kind of tiny cut-down kernel on a low-entropy embedded device and pull gigabytes of random data from /dev/urandom to impact security in a negative way.

Comment: I'm really not interested in getting into a "when to use /dev/urandom versus /dev/random" debate... I just need the above question answered, irrespective of the many wonderful uses for /dev/urandom. The application we are creating requires lots of true-random entropy, not CSPRNG output.

Comment: Care to explain what specific requirement you have that /dev/urandom doesn't solve? The term "true-random entropy" doesn't make any sense in this context.

Comment: An N bit secret taken from a true-random oracle takes as long to guess as any number of secret bits of CSPRNG seeded with an N-bit key. So, if you have an application where each new bit must double the expected time to guess the secret, you need to approximate a true-random oracle as closely as possible, which even a CSPRNG does not do. For example, it is trivial to see that an AES128-CTR mode CSPRNG is not uniformly random since every 128 bit block of the CSPRNG output is strictly non-repeating. This is deficient for our application.

Comment: @Clayton you seem to be under the impression that /dev/random does not use a CSPRNG.

Comment: @tylerl: But it does not *merely* use a CSPRNG... I was responding to Polynomial's suggestion that we just use /dev/urandom for our application.

Comment: Why is there such rigorous lecturing about what he *explicitly asked to avoid?* It's not an X-Y problem on the asker's part here, it's just the "me-too-ego" out of control on the commentators parts. Clayton very, very clearly wants >= N bits of *entropy* in his N bits of randomness. I'm sorry if everyone else was too inattentive and was confused by the difference during their noob times, but years later when people come from google (*ahem*) looking for simply the token `RNDADDENTROPY`, it's a huge pain to see all these "me-too"ers insisting that everyone is as confused as them. Please stop.

Comment: @Polynomial `/dev/urandom` does not use AES-CTR. It used SHA-1, and now uses ChaCha20.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all, to answer your question directly: **This cannot be done. It is purposefully not allowed.**

You can, in fact write to /dev/random and it will mix your input into the random pool, potentially improving the quality of the output. But it won't update the entropy_count and unlock /dev/random for reading, because *that would be **cheating***. Otherwise you'd be able to do something like this:

```
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/random  # Sup dawg, I heard you like random pools...
```

Except that you can. Sort of.

There's an ioctl called `RNDADDENTROPY` available on /dev/random that updates the entropy pool and then increments the entropy_count accordingly. The idea is to allow you to read from a hardware RNG in userspace and dump it into the kernel pool without writing your own driver. Nifty. And while anyone is allowed to dump their entropy into  /dev/random (it can't *hurt*), only root is allowed to use `RNDADDENTROPY`.

And yes, there is a tool out there that allows you to do this relatively easily; it's called `rngd`. Its primary purpose is to read from an RNG like `/dev/hwrandom` or your processor's `RDRAND` instruction, and constantly re-seed your entropy pool as it gets low. But it takes an arbitrary filename for input, so yes, you can even do this:

```
rngd -r /dev/urandom
```

Which, in all honesty, is not entirely unlike doing this:

```
ln -sf /dev/urandom /dev/random
```

But as I stated originally, **that doesn't mean that you can use this tool to make the kernel *use your file as its source of entropy.*** That bit, at least, is not allowed. You can use it as *an additional* source of entropy mixed in with all the others, but not *the only* source of entropy.

If you're convinced your file is of prime-grade randomness, then just use that. You don't *have to* inject it through the kernel's entropy estimation system. If instead you have a mechanism for generating TRNGs, then by all means dump it in there with all the rest of the entropy sources; `rngd` makes that pretty simple.

I won't bother telling you about the utter absurdity of religiously avoiding /dev/urandom on real servers, as clearly you've heard that lecture several times and choose not to listen.

But for everyone else, the difference between /dev/random and /dev/urandom only matters immediately at startup on devices without reasonable sources of randomness (like some embedded devices), where the startup conditions are precisely repeatable, and where the random pool is not saved between boots. In all other cases, any theoretical attack  against /dev/urandom would require techniques and technology that literally do not exist, and are not expected to ever exist, ever.

**From the wording of your question, you seem to be under the impression that /dev/random outputs the result of a TRNG, while /dev/urandom uses a PRNG.** This is not accurate. The only difference in output is that `random` will "lock up" if it's generating bytes faster than it's observing random events, while `urandom` will not. Otherwise they both run the exact same code on their respective pools. Neither directly outputs the raw bits from a TRNG. Both use random events to constantly re-seed a PRNG.

Comment: This answered my question, thank you. I really do understand the difference between /dev/random and /dev/urandom, and your explanation for why the system is not set up to do what I was thinking to do also makes sense.

Comment: My file is of "prime grade randomness" (basically, white noise that has been post-processed through an off-the-shelf CSPRNG but *compressed* not expanded). The difference between our application and others is the need to generate "bulk true randomness", rather than sip a little true randomness from /dev/random and stretch it out through a CSPRNG.

As for server security, the application is a distributed peer-to-peer system, so the security of individual servers in the network is mostly irrelevant to the overall security of the distributed system.

Comment: Apropos cheating: have a look at [this scary Google search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22rngd+r+/dev/urandom%22).

Comment: Linux could do everyone a favor and take the bsd approach here. Maybe create a new char device called /dev/pedanticrandom that keeps the current entropy rules.

Comment: Small nitpick, but it's `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`, not root, which is allowed to use that ioctl.

Answer (score 3):

Given everything you said, you should probably read directly from your file instead of from `/dev/random`.  As you apparently don't trust how `/dev/random` works (perhaps you read [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/338.pdf)) then be declarative, and don't place your trust in it.

You should realize by now that there should be no way anyone can be allowed to inject data directly into the entropy pool.  Otherwise it would be an attack vector that could compromise SSL/TLS key generation, and all the bad guys would be doing it already.

If you insist on pressing forward, check out how `rng-tools` inserts data into the entropy pool.  It's designed to integrate the output from a hardware RNG, and you could modify it to read from your file instead of from a hardware device. My concern is that even if you provide enough data from your file, `/dev/random` may block if it doesn't get enough entropy from its other sources.  It's not supposed to get all its entropy bits from a single source, so no matter how fast you supply them, I think it might block.

If you are using an actual hardware random number generator to create your files, I'd consider using `rng-tools` to tie it directly into the entropy pool without the intermediate step of committing it to the file system.

The nice thing about this approach is that it reduces the risk of your file being a corrupting influence on random numbers (the data is mixed with other sources of entropy) and it reduces the risk of an attacker copying your file and learning your random numbers (due to the other sources of entropy).

Comment: It's not that we don't trust /dev/random - it works for its ordinary applications... it's that our application is a little different than your usual "I want a key to encrypt something, can you give me some high-quality secret bits, please?" We need to generate massive quantities of true random tokens that cannot have any conceivable relationship between the bits, whether cryptographic or otherwise. We do use a CSPRNG to process the bits, but we do it in a way that we end up with *fewer* output bits than input bits to the CSPRNG, that is, we are compressing, not stretching.

Answer (score 0):

On most Linux systems, the entropy pool used by [/dev/random](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c) is [initialized at boot](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/startupman/linux_surandom.html) using `/var/run/random-seed`.  If this process were omitted,  then two identical servers using the same distribution of Linux may have an identical boot sequence and would therefore have an identical /dev/random state.

To prevent this from happening,  upon shutdown the current value of the `/dev/random` entropy pool is saved off into `/var/run/random-seed`,  and then restored upon boot.  Making everyone's entropy pool a little different,  which is a great design.

Comment: Welcome back, @Rook. You've been largely absent for a while.

Comment: You have that path wrong -- `/var/run` is a tmpfs and therefore deleted on shutdown. I didn't Google it, but my Ubuntu system appears to use `/var/lib/urandom/random-seed`.

Comment: @Matt Nordhoff I pulled the path from the init script.  The path is distro dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the kernel's entropy counter requires the `RNDADDENTROPY` ioctl.

The easiest way to call it is to use the `rngd` daemon from the `rng-tools` package:

```
rngd -r /path/to/F
```

(Note: `rngd` expected this to be a hardware device, so when it reaches the end of the file, it will complain that the entropy source is no longer working.)